# How to recognize logs from terminal

Tags: command-line, python

I am running a `.py` file from terminal. I want to recognize in real time when I am getting a specific error so if does I can kill the process and start again.

I found the `script` tool but it doesn't stored logs in real time. I did not found any tool that do it. Can someone help me with that?

Comment: ?!?! you do not need a tool for that. Use a "try except" clause to trap errors. See https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp "when I am getting a specific error so if does I can kill the process and start again" and this reads more like you want a service. https://github.com/torfsen/python-systemd-tutorial systemd can auto-restart script on error.

Comment: I know that I can do it but I am working a lot with open source so I don't want to search inside every script where the error is.

Comment: Do you mean respawn on certain stderr? Something like `./program.py 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep 'someError' && ./program.py`work once.. If program is currently running maybe using `strace`.

Answer (score 0):

Although I find Rinzwinds solution pretty neat I can suggest something that fits to your description.

You can make your python scripts create their logs by adding a function inheriting this:

```
def log(logname = "name_of_file.txt", data = "some_data"):
    f.open(logname, "a")
    f.write("The Text you want as log for " + data + "..\n")  
    f.close()
```

And calling it in the neccessary places by

```
log("name_of_file.txt", "Data_to_be_logged")
```

The log file that you create like that will be stored in the working directory of your script.

If your script is in

```
/path/to/your/python_script/your_script.py
```

the self made log file will be there:

```
/path/to/your/python_script/name_of_file.txt
```

And then you can open another terminal besides your terminal from which you run the scripts and enter:

```
tail -f /path/to/your/python_script/name_of_file.txt
```

The tail command outputs the last lines of a text file and the parameter -f makes it follow your logfile in realtime. To stop 'live monitoring' with tail you can simply ctrl+c.